На запускается клиент в Kotlin/Js
При компиляторе LEGACY такоей код gradle нормально работает и запускает клиент в браузере.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    js(LEGACY) {
        useCommonJs()
        browser {
            println("зашли в browser")
            distribution {
                directory = project.file("../www/static")
            }
            runTask {
                devServer?.run {
                    proxy = mutableMapOf("/" to "http://localhost:8080")
                    port = 3000
                    static = mutableListOf("$buildDir/processedResources/frontend/main")
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }

    sourceSets {
        ///
}

dependencies {
    add("jsTestImplementation", "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js")
    add("jsTestImplementation", npm("enzyme", enzymeVersion))
    add("jsTestImplementation", npm("enzyme-adapter-react-16", enzymeAdapterVersion))
}

Сменил компилятор на IR, и теперь в браузере по адресу localhost:3000 не открывается страница. В логах ошибок нет, пишет только
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
46 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 43 up-to-date

Waiting for changes to input files of tasks... (ctrl-d then enter to exit)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как правильно написать, чтобы работало на ir компиляторе?
